# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (index):1

Tags: javascript, jquery

Все скобки закрыты, подключение полсе подключения Jquery, в чем проблема не понимаю.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#search").keyup(function() {
            var name = $('#search').val();
    
            if (name === "") {
                $("#search_success").html("");
                $("#display").css("display", "none");
            } else {
    
                $.ajax({
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $(".louding_bar").css("display", "block");
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "handler/handler_search.php",
                    data: {
                        search: name
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#display").css("display", "block");
                        $('#search_success').html(response);
                        $(".louding_bar").css("display", "none");
                   
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Видимо возвращается некорректный html

Answer (score 0):

Все верно handler_search.php возвращал некорректный HTML код.